# Take user input in Yii2 console command

Tags: php, yii2

I want to create a console command in Yii2 where I can take the input from the user.

I have looked into the Yii2 documentation here-

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-console.html

But I could not find anything helpful.

I have also searched on Google and StackOverflow with no luck.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

CLI command prompt for any user string:

```
class CronController extends yii\console\Controller
{
   public function actionSendTestmail()
   {
      $emailTo = \yii\helpers\BaseConsole::input("Recipient email: ");
      ...
   }
}
```

or just ask for confirmation [yes|no]:

```
class CronController extends yii\console\Controller
{
   public function actionSendTestmail()
   {
      $emailTo = Yii::$app->params["email.to"];
      if(!$this->confirm("Send email to {$emailTo}?")){
         exit("Sending email interrupted.\n")
      }
      ...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out  yii\helpers\BaseConsole helper class method input().

```
input('Enter your name');
```

Will prompt you for your name.

Or you can define arguments for the action method to pass values to the action.

```
static function actionDoSomething (arg1, arg2, ...);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method `prompt()` provided in the `yii\console\Controller` that calls the `yii\helpers\BaseConsole::prompt()` and gives you additional control to validate the input too after the user enters or just mark it as required so that it is not empty

```
$code = $this->prompt(
    'Enter 4-Chars-Pin',
    [
        'required' => true,
        'validator' => function ($input, &$error) {
            if (strlen($input) !== 4) {
                $error = 'The Pin must be exactly 4 chars!';
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        },
    ]
);
```